# How to do model inference on a multimodal model from hugginface using sagemaker

Tags: boto3, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface

I'm following this python notebook tutorial https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/19_serverless_inference/sagemaker-notebook.ipynb
The tutorial works but I'm trying to change the model to a multimodal model that takes text and an image as an input.
After some research I've narrowed down my problem to the way that data is being sent most likley.
And it seems that I need some type of serializer.
I would appreciate any recommendations on how to proceed or what to try to deploy this model succesfully and run some inference.

```
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel
from sagemaker.serializers import JSONSerializer, BaseSerializer
from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer, BaseDeserializer
from sagemaker.serverless import ServerlessInferenceConfig

from typing import Dict
import json
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image


class TextImageSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/json'
    def __init__(self):
        self.json_serializer = JSONSerializer()

    def _text_input(self, data):
        return {'question': data}

    def _image_input(self, data):
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
        buffer = BytesIO()
        img.save(buffer, format='PNG')
        return {'image': buffer.getvalue()}

    def serialize(self, data: Dict) -> bytes:
        text_data = data.get('question')
        image_data = data.get('image')

        if text_data and not image_data:
            return self.json_serializer.serialize(self._text_input(text_data))
        elif image_data and not text_data:
            return self.json_serializer.serialize(self._image_input(image_data))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Data must contain either 'question' or 'image' keys, but not both.")

# Hub Model configuration. <https://huggingface.co/models>
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID': 'naver-clova-ix/donut-base-finetuned-docvqa',
    'HF_TASK': 'question-answering'
}

huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
   env=hub,                      
   role=role,                    
   transformers_version="4.17.0",  
   pytorch_version="1.10.2",      
   py_version='py38',       
)

serverless_config = ServerlessInferenceConfig(
    memory_size_in_mb=3072, max_concurrency=10,
)

predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    serializer=TextImageSerializer(),
    serverless_inference_config=serverless_config,
)

payload = {
    'question': "what is the document title",
    'image': open("document.png", "rb").read()
}

res = predictor.predict(data=payload)
```

I have tried using different serializers but am not sure if the serializer is the problem in the first place.

Comment: I deployed Llava Llama https://huggingface.co/liuhaotian/llava-llama-2-13b-chat-lightning-preview/discussions/3 to SageMaker with the default deployment card (non serverless). What model did you try, and could you get it working non serverless vs serverless?

Answer (score 0):

All SageMaker inference services require a Serializer and Deserializer. The [SageMaker SDK for Python](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is helpful in this regard, the available serializers can be found [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/serializers.html).

I have not used a `TextImageSerializer`, but it looks like a custom implementation. Some general points below:

- It looks like `TextImageSerializer.serialize()` does not return any serialized content. There’s no return statement for *both* text and image.
- SageMaker Serverless Inference is often tricky with non-standard implementations. If you are able to perform inference with the HF model locally, I would recommend a [SageMaker Real-time Inference Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/realtime-endpoints.html) with a custom inference.py file.

  - There’s a great tutorial [here](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/17_custom_inference_script/sagemaker-notebook.ipynb).
  - Essentially, clone the model repo from Hugging Face, create code/inference.py with a function to initialise the model, and a function to perform inference. Zip the whole model directory and upload to S3, then pass the S3 URI to SageMaker and it will produce an endpoint.

**N.B.** SageMaker’s own documentation for HF-based inference is *very* poor. [This notebook](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/17_custom_inference_script/sagemaker-notebook.ipynb) is the most definitive guide I have found on this subject. [Hugging Face’s SageMaker Documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/index) is also rather helpful.