# How to perform inference with a Llava Llama model deployed to SageMaker from Huggingface?

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface, huggingface-hub

I deployed a Llava Llama Huggingface model (https://huggingface.co/liuhaotian/llava-llama-2-13b-chat-lightning-preview/discussions/3) to a SageMaker Domain + Endpoint by using the deployment card provided by Huggingface:

```
import sagemaker
import boto3
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel

try:
    role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
except ValueError:
    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    role = iam.get_role(RoleName='sagemaker_execution_role')['Role']['Arn']

# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID': 'liuhaotian/llava-llama-2-13b-chat-lightning-preview',
    'HF_TASK': 'text-generation'
}

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    transformers_version='4.26.0',
    pytorch_version='1.13.1',
    py_version='py39',
    env=hub,
    role=role, 
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, # number of instances
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge' # ec2 instance type
)
```

The deployment sets the `HF_TASK` as `text-generation`. Llava Llama however is a multi modal text + image model. So the big question is how I'd perform an inference / prediction. I'd need to pass the image and also the text prompt. Other image + text API such as Imagen or Chooch accepts a base64 encoded image data. I know I need to do more than that since for example the models are trained with a specific dimension dataset (I think the Llava Llama model it might be 336x336), and Imagen or Chooch as a PaaS service does the cropping / resizing / padding.

Llava Llama has a demo page https://llava-vl.github.io/ which uses Gradio user interface. So I cannot tell where and how is the model hosted. However we might be able to decipher the solution from the source code. This `get_image` function is I think important, it does the resize / crop / pad: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/a4269fbf014af3cab1f1d172914493fae8b74820/llava/conversation.py#L109 and that is invoked from https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/a4269fbf014af3cab1f1d172914493fae8b74820/llava/serve/gradio_web_server.py#L138

We can see that there will be some magic tokens which will mark the beginning and end of the image and separate the text prompt (https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/a4269fbf014af3cab1f1d172914493fae8b74820/llava/serve/gradio_web_server.py#L154). We can see that the text prompt is truncated to 1536 tokens (?) for text to image generation mode and 1200 tokens for image QnA mode. A compound prompt is assembled with the help of these tokens (https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/a4269fbf014af3cab1f1d172914493fae8b74820/llava/conversation.py#L287) and templates (https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/a4269fbf014af3cab1f1d172914493fae8b74820/llava/conversation.py#L71). The image is also appended as a base64 string, in PNG format: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/a4269fbf014af3cab1f1d172914493fae8b74820/llava/conversation.py#L154

When I try to invoke the endpoint for a an inference / prediction

```
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor
from base64 import b64encode

endpoint = 'huggingface-pytorch-inference-2023-09-23-08-55-26-117'
ENCODING = "utf-8"
IMAGE_NAME = "eiffel_tower_336.jpg"

payload = {
    "inputs": "Describe the content of the image in great detail ",
}
with open(IMAGE_NAME, 'rb') as f:
    byte_content = f.read()
    base64_bytes = b64encode(byte_content)
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode(ENCODING)

predictor = Predictor(endpoint)
inference_response = predictor.predict(data=payload)
print (inference_response)
```

I get an error, that `ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Body, value: {'inputs': 'Describe the content of the image in great detail '}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object`

This HuggingFace discussion says https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/can-text-to-image-models-be-deployed-to-a-sagemaker-endpoint/20120 that an inference.py need to be created. I don't know what the Llava Llama has though. I tried to look at the files of the model, but I don't see relevant meta data about this.

This StackOverflow entry [How to do model inference on a multimodal model from hugginface using sagemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76197446/how-to-do-model-inference-on-a-multimodal-model-from-hugginface-using-sagemaker) is about a serverless deployment case, but it uses a custom TextImageSerializer serializer. Should I try to use something like that?

This Reddittor suggests https://www.reddit.com/r/LocalLLaMA/comments/16pzn88/how_to_parametrize_a_llava_llama_model/ some kind of a CLIP encoding. I'm uncertain if I really need to do that or the model is able to encode?

Other references:

- Asking at the model: https://huggingface.co/liuhaotian/llava-llama-2-13b-chat-lightning-preview/discussions/3
- GitHub Discussion: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/discussions/454
- HuggingFace Discussion: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-use-llava-with-huggingface/52315
- Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/LocalLLaMA/comments/16pzn88/how_to_parametrize_a_llava_llama_model/

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR;
Until there will be better model cards (although https://huggingface.co/shauray/Llava-Llama-2-7B-hf seems to have a meaningful usage, but I don't know where `from transformers import LlavaProcessor, LlavaForCausalLM` comes from, see https://huggingface.co/shauray/Llava-Llama-2-7B-hf/discussions/1), S seems to be all over the place.
So I got fed up, went ahead and used replicate.com, see https://replicate.com/yorickvp/llava-13b/api

```
import replicate
output = replicate.run(
    "yorickvp/llava-13b:2facb4a474a0462c15041b78b1ad70952ea46b5ec6ad29583c0b29dbd4249591",
    input=dict(
        image=open("eiffel_tower_336.jpg", "rb"),
        prompt="Describe what is on the photo in great detail, be very verbose"
    )
)
# The yorickvp/llava-13b model can stream output as it's running.
# The predict method returns an iterator, and you can iterate over that output.
for item in output:
    # https://replicate.com/yorickvp/llava-13b/versions/2facb4a474a0462c15041b78b1ad70952ea46b5ec6ad29583c0b29dbd4249591/api#output-schema
    print(item, end="")
```

It's that simple.

Detailed debug: the [LLaVA GitHub repo](https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/) should contain how the CLI or the GUI interacts with the back-end.
As far as the CLI goes: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/main/llava/serve/cli.py

1. We can see there's a `conv_mode` based on model type. In our case it is Llama 2 https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/6bfd90754621c0277672d1418336a31d976c4ec3/llava/serve/cli.py#L34C5-L35C36

```
if 'llama-2' in model_name.lower():
    conv_mode = "llava_llama_2"
```

That means https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/f47c16e4aeac6d4d61259800ca9cd33b26824113/llava/conversation.py#L277

```
conv_llava_llama_2 = Conversation(
    system="You are a helpful language and vision assistant. "
           "You are able to understand the visual content that the user provides, "
           "and assist the user with a variety of tasks using natural language.",
    roles=("USER", "ASSISTANT"),
    version="llama_v2",
    messages=(),
    offset=0,
    sep_style=SeparatorStyle.LLAMA_2,
    sep="<s>",
    sep2="</s>",
)
```

We can see the separators and separator style mainly here. The `LLAMA_2` `SeparatorStyle`:

```
        elif self.sep_style == SeparatorStyle.LLAMA_2:
            wrap_sys = lambda msg: f"<<SYS>>\n{msg}\n<</SYS>>\n\n"
            wrap_inst = lambda msg: f"[INST] {msg} [/INST]"
```

2. Image handling: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/f47c16e4aeac6d4d61259800ca9cd33b26824113/llava/serve/cli.py#L54

```
    image = load_image(args.image_file)
    # Similar operation in model_worker.py
    image_tensor = process_images([image], image_processor, args)
    if type(image_tensor) is list:
        image_tensor = [image.to(model.device, dtype=torch.float16) for image in image_tensor]
    else:
        image_tensor = image_tensor.to(model.device, dtype=torch.float16)
```

The `load_image` simply loads the binary image data irrespective of it's format (jpg, png, etc).
Then the `process_images` converts the image to tensors: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/f47c16e4aeac6d4d61259800ca9cd33b26824113/llava/mm_utils.py#L28C5-L28C19
Before the conversion it somewhat regularizes the image to be square with padding. For best reuslt I'd already provide a square 336 x 336px or 224 x 224px image.
Then this tenzorized image is interpolated into the prompt, looks like to be prepended with an image separator token: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/f47c16e4aeac6d4d61259800ca9cd33b26824113/llava/serve/cli.py#L75

```
if model.config.mm_use_im_start_end:
    inp = DEFAULT_IM_START_TOKEN + DEFAULT_IMAGE_TOKEN + DEFAULT_IM_END_TOKEN + '\n' + inp
else:
    inp = DEFAULT_IMAGE_TOKEN + '\n' + inp
conv.append_message(conv.roles[0], inp)
```

For the actual inference the `image_tensor` is passed on as a parameter to the `model`. The `model` is not present at the client side though when calling an API.

2. Let's try to see maybe how the GRadio front-end calls the back-end: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/main/llava/serve/gradio_web_server.py
   Here is the payload assmebled: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/f47c16e4aeac6d4d61259800ca9cd33b26824113/llava/serve/gradio_web_server.py#L224

```
pload = {
    "model": model_name,
    "prompt": prompt,
    "temperature": float(temperature),
    "top_p": float(top_p),
    "max_new_tokens": min(int(max_new_tokens), 1536),
    "stop": state.sep if state.sep_style in [SeparatorStyle.SINGLE, SeparatorStyle.MPT] else state.sep2,
    "images": f'List of {len(state.get_images())} images: {all_image_hash}',
}
```

And then the `images` are substituted: `pload['images'] = state.get_images()`. `state` is in the conversation object, which we already looked at: https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA/blob/f47c16e4aeac6d4d61259800ca9cd33b26824113/llava/conversation.py#L109
It standardizes the image and looks like also base64 encodes the PNG format image.

I got tired of trying combinations, I kept getting

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "\u0027llava\u0027"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LLaVa is now natively supported in the Transformers library, this should now be a lot easier to deploy.

Docs: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/llava

Checkpoints on the hub: https://huggingface.co/llava-hf